# Lerna return lerna success run No packages found with the lifecycle script 'build'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, nvm, lerna

when i try to run `lerna run build --stream` it runs a long time and fails with `lerna success run No packages found with the lifecycle script 'build'`. The repository was up to date and i have 0 changes done there. For my colleagues everything worked fine.

[picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEkdI.png)

I tried already to delete the node_modules file in my react repo, to clean the cache of nvm and node and also to reinstall node. The issue also only appears in one Repo that uses lerna for an other repo everything works fine. That other repo uses an other node version that I change with nvm. (node version of the buggy repo: 18.14.2) I tried also to run the project in another ide I am currently using Webstorm, but I also tried it in VSC.

I expect that the build success and all packages will be found.